# How to define embedded /anonymous fields (go struct )

Tags: struct, go, literals

I'm trying to initialize  an embedded struct. However the compiler says I can't mix values and and value initializers. What's the correct syntax  ? 
httpCl is of type `*requests.Trans`

```
type clTran struct {
    *requests.Trans
    uCh chan user
}

func main() {
    httpCl, err := requests.tr(px)
    clT := clTran{httpCl, uCh: uCh}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you label fields in a struct literal (which you usually should) all of them need to be labeled. In the case of embedding, the field takes the name of its type. So

```
clT := clTran {
    Trans: httpCl,
    uCh: uCh,
}
```

Note that this field name applies to accessing and writing too, `clT.Trans = httpCl` is valid and will write to the embedded field.

Comment: What if there would be two anonymous fields of different types but with the same type name ? e.g. requests.Trans and brequests.Trans  ?

Comment: In this case, order matters.

Comment: @FUZxxl I have a hard time to find this in the specs. Is it mentioned ?